# Drawing rectangle using mouse

Tags: java, events, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to draw a rectangle on a java applet using mouse drag event and make it stay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115359/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-on-a-java-applet-using-mouse-drag-event-and-make-it-stay)

Hello. 
I would like to know how I can draw rectangle using mousedragged event. I know that I must record mouse location using class Point. I need to implement paint function in paint method and in mousedragged call it or my paint code should implement in mousedragged event?

At this time I put my code in mouse dragged event. This is code:

```
@Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        super.mousePressed(e);
        System.out.println("f.getGlassPane() mousePressed");
        if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)


        frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);

        startPoint=e.getPoint();

        Graphics2D g = null;
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Rectangle2D prostokat = new Rectangle2D.Double();
        prostokat.setFrameFromDiagonal(e.getPoint().x, e.getPoint().y,startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5F));
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.fill(prostokat);
        g2.draw(prostokat);

    }

    });
```

Comment: There are a lot of comparable questions on SO - this one could have an answer for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115359/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-on-a-java-applet-using-mouse-drag-event-and-make-it-stay

Comment: use mousePressed and store the location and store the location of the mouseReleased. With those values you can calculate your rect.

Comment: I have a question. When I will be painting my rectangle using mousedragged, he will be blinking? In example from Andreas_D post when I draw rectangle he blinking. I don't want to see this effect

Comment: `JPanel` is double buffered by default; this is usually satisfactory. +1 for using `AlphaComposite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll also need to handle `mouseReleased` and `mouseDragged`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797862) and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel).

Comment: This second link is exacly what I want. Thx a lot :)